# Launching the graphical interface for setting environment variables

Tags: windows-7, command-line

In **Windows 7**, what command launches the graphical interface for setting environment variables displayed below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to search for "environment variables" in the Windows Start Menu:

1. Either Click the Windows logo on the Start Menu or hit the "Windows" key on your keyboard
2. Type "environment variables" in the search bar
3. Select either "Edit environment variables for your account" or "Edit the system environment variables" depending on which you would like to edit. You will need local administrator rights to edit system environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

It's a sub-dialog that can't be opened directly from what I've found. You can open the System Properties dialog on the Advanced tab however:

```
control.exe sysdm.cpl,System,3
```

There's also an executable that does the same:

```
SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe
```

You can create a shortcut and enable *Run as Administrator* in the advanced settings if required (to edit system environment variables using a regular user account, not just your own).